# AddAutoMapper not found in .NET Core with AutoMapper

Tags: automapper, automapper-8

Using Visual Studio 2019 I installed AutoMapper version 8.1.0 via NuGet.  When I try to add the `services.AddAutoMapper()` call though in my `Startup.cs` file I get a compiler error that the method doesn't exist.

I've already tried to do a `dotnet clean` and `dotnet restore` from the NuGet console but that didn't help.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: Thanks, @LucianBargaoanu.  I had installed your base package and didn't realize your NuGet link was pointing at a different package.  Also, the "here" link goes to a 404.

Comment: I see that, but I have no idea why. A PR is welcome :)

Answer (score 33):

It is an old thread, however the solution for this problem is to install `Automapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` package along with your `automapper` package.
I hope it helps.